# Can't connect using SQLSRV driver on Windows but works with DBLIB on Linux - PHP & SQL Server 2012 Standard

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 (not express) over Windows using the PHP drivers Microsoft provides, called "sqlsrv", but it won't work no matter what I do. I tried everything, like specifying the instance name, the protocol, the port, but it just won't work. However, it works like a charm using DBLib, the problem is that it is deprecated on Windows due to some security issues. Thankfully both production and test servers are linux based, so I can use DBLib for that matter, but can't do anything locally. We are a team of 3 people and we work over the same directory and server, which means that using Git is basically pointless. Am I missing something? Does the SQL Server need some extra config to work? My code should be ok since it can connect to an Azure SQL dedicated server flawlessly. Of course port 1433 is open and stuff.

```
function SQLConn($h,$db,$user,$pass){
    $dsn= 'sqlsrv:server='.$h.';database='.$db;

    try {
        $result = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $result='Connection to SQL Server failed: ' . $e->getMessage(). "\n";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The errors it returns are connection errors, like:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]
```

Specifying the instance name returns:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]
```

Using PHP 7.3. Help please :C

Comment: You mention things about a port, but the first error indicates that you are trying to connect using Named Pipes and not TCP/IP.  Check to make sure that the Named Pipes protocol is enabled on your SQL Server instance, or change your connection to use TCP/IP instead (and make sure TCP/IP is enabled on your server instance).

Comment: I did try, putting "tcp:X.X.X.X" on the DSN, and still fails to connect:`TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: Right, but did you make sure that the protocol is enabled on the SQL Server Instance?

Comment: Yep, everything is on and configured to allow remote access. Now here is the weird thing: sqlsrv is working if I use the local IP of the server (192.168.0.X), but won't connect though our public IP, like the port is closed, not forwarded to the server or something, but it isn't because DBLib connects without any problem at all. I am missing something very stupid but don't know what.

Comment: DBLib connects just fine _from the same machine that you're having problems with_?  Can you ping the public IP from that same machine?

Comment: Yup. It only fails with sqlsrv for some reason :(